# Execute SSIS from remote machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to execute an SSIS package from an .net application that's on a remote machine. The machine running the application does not have SSIS installed.

I know this can be accomplished using T-SQL with xp_cmdshell http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3372131/Using-xpcmdshell.htm but am unable to use this approach because of security issues.

I would like to put store this package as an Agent job on the remote server (running sql server 2008) and execute it though the Agent service. I found an article about that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx#agent but am unable to find out how to pass the package in variables.

These variables will change from each run and I know I could store them in the database and load them while executing the package but it seems a hacky solution. Is anyone aware of a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered/read about package configurations? You may want to read that if you have not done so already. Also, read about the DTEXEC utility which is the command line SSIS executable. You can easily pass variables through a batchfile and DTEXEC utility.

Comment: Package configurations seem to fit my needs here well. Thanks!